# AWS CloudShell Error 'Unable to start the environment...'

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudshell

It works in my root account but not in the IAM user account even though i have attached 'AWSCloudShellFullAccess' policy to the user group. And i have checked in policy simulator there i see no errors. I even switched browsers(root user works but not with IAM user), switched regions and restarted the environment but still same error which is 'Unable to start the environment. To retry, refresh the browser or restart by selecting Actions, Restart AWS CloudShell.'

I also tried by creating new IAM user and assigned 'AdministratorAccess' and 'AWSCloudShellFullAccess' policy basically admin which should work but it didn't. And no DENY policy is found. idk what i'm doing wrong... is there a policy that i'm missing out ?

Answer (score 0):

So i was able to resolve this issue. Few things to try to create CloudShell environment:

- Time Synchronization: Make sure Your machine time is accurate. It means its correct based on world time.  did you try from another machine to see if its working there?  may be any time sync related issue?
- Check in different regions..
- check AWSCloudShellFullAccess policy to ensure it has below JSON data.

```
   {
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Action": [
                "cloudshell:*"
            ],
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ]
}
```

- Check in different browser to see if it works in different browser or not. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cloudshell/latest/userguide/troubleshooting.html
- Did you deleted cloudshell home directory or something? Try after resetting home directory. But it can DELETE all your data exists in home directory. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cloudshell/latest/userguide/vm-specs.html#deleting-home-directory
- check if any DENY policy created for it. remove that.
- It is possible your account is not 100% verified. Try this: Create a CloudFront distribution if you get the below error it confirms your account is unverified or if you can create 2 distributions and can't create the 3rd one.

> Your account must be verified before you can add new CloudFront
> resources. To verify your account, please contact AWS Support
> (https://console.aws.amazon.com/support/home#/ ) and include this
> error message.

Click the support link

1. Navigate to:
   Support / New case / Service limit increase
2. Limit type:
   CloudFront Distributions
3. In Requests select:
   Limit: Web Distributions per Account
   New limit value: <TYPE_YOUR_NEW_VALUE_HERE>

MY CASE: In my case, I had 2 distributions, wanted to create 3rd, but couldn't. So I have put as <TYPE_YOUR_NEW_VALUE_HERE> a number 10.

Note: If nothing works choose last option as your last resort to confirm your account is verified.